# No hay ningún elemento ViewData de tipo 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>' con la clave 'Codigo'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Tengo un DropdownList en donde muestro una lista sacada de una tabla de una base de datos, el problema es cuando hago un save muestra el siguiente error:
No hay ningún elemento ViewData de tipo 'IEnumerable' con la clave 'Codigo'.

Controller

```html
public ActionResult Analisis(int id)
{
  if (Session["Nombre"] != null)
  {
    ViewData["Nombre"] = Session["Nombre"].ToString();
    List<ClassMuestra> lst_zonas = (from d in bd.TblZonas select new ClassMuestra{
      Codigo = d.Codigo,
      Descripcion = d.Descripcion 
     }).OrderBy(x=>x.Descripcion).ToList();

     List<SelectListItem> zonas = lst_zonas.ConvertAll(d =>
     {
      return new SelectListItem()
      {
        Text = d.Descripcion.ToString(),
        Value = d.Codigo.ToString(),
        selected = false
       };
      });
      ViewBag.zonas = zonas;
   }
   else
   {
     return RedirectToAction("Index", "Login");
    }
return View();
}
```

Para guardar uso otro metodo en el controller

```html
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Analisis(Analisis model)
{
  Analisis.Id = model.Id;
  Analisis.Nombre = model.Nombre;
  Analisis.Codigo = model.Codigo;
  //...etc
  bd.Analisis.Add(Analisis);
  bd.SaveChanges();
  
   return View();
}
```

Cshtml

```html
 @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Codigo, IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.zonas, "--Seleccione la zona--", new { @class = "form-control form-control-sm" })
 @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Codigo, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
```

Class

```html
public class ClassMuestra
{
  public string Codigo { get; set; }
  public string Descripcion { get; set; } 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La vista que se retorna con `return View()` espera datos para llenar un `DropDown` que no se le están pasando.

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Analisis(Analisis model)
    {
      Analisis.Id = model.Id;
      Analisis.Nombre = model.Nombre;
      Analisis.Codigo = model.Codigo;
      //...etc
      bd.Analisis.Add(Analisis);
      bd.SaveChanges();


       // esta vista tiene un dropdown pero sus datos no se han
       // preparado
       return View();
    }
```

En lugar de `return View()` se puede usar un `RedirecToAction("accion")` para evitar ese problema, eso si no hay errores de validación que requieran enviar de nuevo los datos ingresados por el usuario.